# Segmentation Fault when using strtok and fgets

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

So, I have a program that takes initial arguments from the command line and attempts to see how many times they occur for a given input.

For example in terminal you would write something like this:

```
./main cat nap dog
```

Then it would say looking for 3 words and you would input the words, followed by a period when you would like it to end:

```
Looking for words:
cat
cat
nap
.
```

The program would then return:

```
Result:
cat: 2
nap: 1
dog: 0
```

I want to implement a way so you can input multiple words on one line and it would still count them.

I have the following function:

```
int process_stream(WordCountEntry entries[], int entry_count)
{
  short line_count = 0;
  char buffer[30];

  while (fgets(buffer, 30, stdin)) {
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
    char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
    while (token != NULL){
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n"); 
      int i = 0;
      while (i < entry_count+1) {
        if (!strcmp(entries[i].word, token))
          entries[i].counter++;
        i++;
      }
      line_count++;
    }
  }
  return line_count;
}
```

I attempt to tokenize each given string using the delimiter of " " and then try to move on to the next line. However, it only separates the first word and then gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: Kind of an incomplete source, but have you included the appropriate header files, and compiled with normal warnings enabled and ensured that your program has no warnings?  Strtok returns a char *, so if you are missing a declaration for it, the compiler assumes an int.   Given that you didn't, on a 64bit machine, I would expect it to fault at the first strcmp.

Comment: I have included all the appropriate header files. In fact, the code does work at the beginning. If I input `cat nap dog` it is able to tokenize the first `cat`, but then it results in a segmentation fault after that.

Comment: Code fails at `if (!strcmp(entries[i].word, token))` when `token == NULL`.

Comment: it's a null reference issue. you need to initialize your new entry as you increment i

Comment: `char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n"); while (token != NULL){ token = strtok(NULL, " \n"); ...` -- where have you used the first `token`? Also, if your terminating character is `'.'`, shouldn't that be `while (token != NULL && *token != '.'){` ?? See also, You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). (answer: No)

Comment: `while (token != NULL && *token != '.'){` I added this condition, but it still does not break at `.`

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways this is wrong:

1. `i < entry_count+1`: Assume `entry_count` is 1; since 1<2, you will be testing against an uninitialized and possibly out-of-bounds `entries[1]`. I think you wanted to write `< entry_count`.
2. `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]=` - so if strlen is 0, you are writing in `buffer[-1]` - there's another segfault right there. I also don't know what the purpose of this line might be.
3. You are testing for `token` not being null before you set it again to `strtok()`. Almost certainly the second time it will be null and you'll be doing `strcmp` against null. There's another segfault right there. You need to move the cycling to the next `strtok` to the end of the loop.
4. `fgets` stops at newline characters anyway, that strtok contraption is unneeded anyway.

Comment: 1. I already have test cases for when it is empty in the main function, so entries[1] would never be initialized anyway.

Comment: 2. I used that code from stack overflow in order to ensure fgets() wouldn't add an extra `\n` anyway.
3. I will change that.
4. I want to be able to read words from the same line, but tokenize them using a space.

Comment: If `entry_count` is 1, you must only be checking against entries[0]. You do not know what `entries[1].word` is pointing at (probably null) so doing a strcmp on that will be a segfault. Revise your condition, because your code is checking `entries[1].word` when `entry_count` is 1.

Comment: 2. Don't use that code from stack overflow, because if you have an empty last line it will segfault or corrupt other data.

Comment: and... it's outside the scope of the question, but if at all possible, use C++ string and stream handling... C I/O and string manipulation is the number one source of misery in the computing world, I hear in professional projects programmers must quietly meditate on programming while eating only bread and water for a full year before they're allowed to touch that.

Comment: Stack Overflow, the number one go-to resource for doing your homework...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is with the loop for breaking the input line into token. The 'strtok' is called twice on the input data, with only one NULL check.

If the second strtok call return NULL, the code will fail (crash) on the strcmp. Consider revising the loop body to:

```
  while (fgets(buffer, 30, stdin)) {
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
    if ( strcmp(buffer, ".") == 0 ) break ;
    char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
    while (token != NULL){
      int i = 0;
      while (i < entry_count+1) {
        if (!strcmp(entries[i].word, token))
          entries[i].counter++;
        i++;
      }
      line_count++;
      // Place strtok here
      token = strtok(NULL, " \n");   }
    }
```

also note that the posted code will fix the problem that cause the first token on every line to be ignored.

Comment: How would I add a conditional here to break when a "." is typed?

Comment: @flutterbug98 code extended to include check for '.'

Answer (score 0):

Your function processes the tokens out of order. You skip the first `token` entirely overwriting the pointer `token` before it is used with:

```
char* token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
while (token != NULL){
  token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
```

Next the following line is superfluous given your delimiter of `" \n"`. The `'\n'` you attempt to overwrite with the following code with never be part of `token`:

```
buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
```

You are using `'.'` to mark the end-of-input so you do not need to process the final line. You avoid this problem you break your nested loop with a simple `goto` statement,  e.g.:

```
    while (fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin)) {
        ...
        while (token != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp (token, "."))               /* compare != '.' */
                goto done;
            ...
    }
    done:;

    return line_count;
}
```

Assuming `entry_count` is the number of elements in `entries`, then your `+1` causes you to read beyond the bounds of `entries` likely resulting in a SegFault. While it is impossible to verify give the complete code that is missing from your question, it looks like you intended:

```
        while (i < entry_count) {               /* +1 causeses UB */
```

Your call to `token = strtok(NULL, " \n");` to get the next token should be the last statement in your loop, not the first, otherwise you have skipped a token.

Putting it altogether, it looks like you would need something similar to:

```
#define MAXC 128    /* max number of characters per word/line */
...
int process_stream (WordCountEntry entries[], int entry_count)
{
    short line_count = 0;
    char buffer[MAXC];
    const char *delim = " \n";                      /* set delim once */

    while (fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin)) {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (token != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp (token, "."))               /* compare != '.' */
                goto done;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < entry_count) {               /* +1 causeses UB */
                if (!strcmp(entries[i].word, token))
                    entries[i].counter++;
                i++;
            }
            line_count++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);            /* now get next token */
        }
    }
    done:;

    return line_count;
}
```

**Short Example**

Per your comments you wanted to be able to handle single-words or multiple-words per-line. The function above does that, but you may have other problems in code you haven't posted. To validate the function above, a short implementation was written. So long as your code provides similar input, the function above will satisfy your needs. The short example used was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NENT  16    /* max number of entries (no. elements in array) */
#define MAXC 128    /* max number of characters per word / line */

typedef struct {
    char word[MAXC];
    int counter;
} WordCountEntry;

int process_stream (WordCountEntry entries[], int entry_count)
{
    short line_count = 0;
    char buffer[MAXC];
    const char *delim = " \n";                      /* set delim once */

    while (fgets (buffer, MAXC, stdin)) {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (token != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp (token, "."))               /* compare != '.' */
                goto done;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < entry_count) {               /* +1 causeses UB */
                if (!strcmp(entries[i].word, token))
                    entries[i].counter++;
                i++;
            }
            line_count++;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);            /* now get next token */
        }
    }
    done:;

    return line_count;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    WordCountEntry wce[NENT] = { { .word = "" } };
    int n = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fputs ("error: insufficient arguments.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < (argc < NENT ? argc : NENT); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (!strcmp (wce[j].word, argv[i]))
                goto next;
        }
        strcpy (wce[i-1].word, argv[i]);
        n++;
        next:;
    }

    puts ("Looking for words:");

    if (!process_stream (wce, n))
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);

    puts ("\nResult:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("%s: %d\n", wce[i].word, wce[i].counter);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/wordcountentry cat nap dog
Looking for words:
cat
cat
nap
.

Result:
cat: 2
nap: 1
dog: 0
```

or with multiple-words per-line:

```
$ ./bin/wordcountentry cat nap dog
Looking for words:
cat dog dog
cat dog
nap .

Result:
cat: 2
nap: 1
dog: 3
```

There may be other problems in your code and it is impossible to be sure this will correct all issues due to the lack of [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but given what you had, this should address the problems that are identifiable, though there may be others.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant  `const char *delim =  " \n";`

Comment: Also, I edited this line `token != NULL && *token != '.'` to this `token != NULL && *token != '.\n'` because I thought it would fix the issue with the code not breaking after I input `.`. However, it did not. This is the while loop conditional btw

Comment: Whoa `*token != '.\n'` is not right. `'.\n'` is not a single-character.

Comment: My code was working well with just one word per line. However, I am trying to make it so that it does work with multiple words per line. Meaning, it would tokenize the lines based on spaces between the words on the SAME line and then add them to the count

Comment: Unfortunately, the first example doesn't break when I input `.`

Comment: Give me a second and I'll double-check. (it was an `&&` to `||` change) That is why an MCVE is needed -- that way I can verify the operation rather than having to post untested code `:)` Also -- ***never skimp on buffer size***, `char buffer[1024]` would adequately handle what most people will type as a line (or if a cat steps on the keyboard) -- `30` won't.

Comment: Thank you for your help. And I'll try for next time to post a more conclusive question.

Comment: Sure, see note about buffer size I added to comment above. Wait the `&&` was correct to begin with. The test of `while (token != NULL && *token != '.')` was proper.